# Java Inheritance Dilemma

Tags: java, android, inheritance

I'm currently working on an Android SDK with essentially two variations, base variation (for third-party developers) and privileged variation (to be used internally).

The privileged SDK just adds additional functionality that the third-party developers do not have direct access to.

My idea was to use macros to selectively remove functionality but Java does not support that.

My next idea was to take the base variation and just extend classes and interfaces in there to produce the privileged variation.

My current issue is as follows using the inheritance approach (which has produced a code smell that indicated to me that there is a probably a better solution):

An instance of `BaseAPI` has an instance of `BaseInterface`, which in some of its methods use `BaseDevice` as parameters.

The privileged SDK has an instance of `PrivilegedAPI`, `PrivilegedInterface`, and `PrivilegedDevice`.

The problem comes with the idea of wanting the interfaces to take either instances of either `BaseDevice` or `PrivilegedDevice`.

I would ideally like this BaseInterface:

```
public interface BaseInterface {
    void deviceConnected(BaseDevice device);
}
```

And this PrivilegedInterface:

```
public interface PrivilegedInterface extends BaseInterface {
    //overwrites deviceConnected in BaseInterface with PrivilegedDevice
    @Override
    void deviceConnected(PrivilegedDevice device);
}
```

But I cannot override `deviceConnected` with a different parameter of `PrivilegedDevice` in `PrivilegedInterface`.

Another idea I had was to utilize build flavors to hide functionality but this didn't seem to fit either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Create an extra method in the interface:(this is a concept of method overloading)

```
public interface BaseInterface {
    void deviceConnected(BaseDevice baseDevice);
    void deviceConnected(PrivilegedDevice privilegedDevice);
```

}

Comment: `PrivilegedDevice` should not be available in `BaseInterface` though

Comment: make Privileged Device(Child) extend from BaseDevice(Parent).

Comment: I have done that, but then in the callback method the device is treated as BaseDevice and therefore does not have access to methods in PrivilegedDevice

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to abstract away the device class.

```
public interface Device {
    void deviceConnected();
}

public class BaseDevice implements Device {

    BaseDevice() {

    }

    void deviceConnected() {

    }
}

public class PrivilegedDevice implements Device {

    PrivilegedDevice() {

    }

    void deviceConnected() {

    }
}
```

Comment: The interface is used for callbacks, so if I am understanding what you are saying correctly then this would not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

This potentially does not solve the problem for people experiencing the same issue in the future, but the overall issue had to do with the hierarchy of my classes and some of their internals.

I was able to actually move some stuff into the `BaseAPI`, get rid of a class that was used inside `BaseDevice`, and basically restructured things in a more logical way. The end result is a few less classes and a more logical structure of my classes.

The code smell was a result of having a few over-complicated pieces in my code.